# LISTEN channel_name; fails due to ' vs. "

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to make the `LISTEN channelname` configurable.

```
queue_listen_name = config["database"]["listen_channel"]
cur.execute("LISTEN %s;", (queue_listen_name,))
```

This piece of code fails however, because postgresql doesn't like single quotes when listening to a channel:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'channel_name'"
LINE 1: LISTEN 'channel_name';
```

It does work when using double quotes (tested on psql).

What can I do? I don't want to build a string myself and then using `cur.execute()` on that string because of obvious SQL injection reasons.

So this is NOT what I want to do:

```
queue_listen_name = "LISTEN {};".format(config["database"]["listen_channel"])
cur.execute(queue_listen_name)
```

Comment: You should never use % formatting or `.format()` on SQL queries. It will lead to SQL injections.

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote "is NOT what I want to do".
Using `%s` is fine with psycopg2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking from manual, both of those should work and are described as "safe":

```
# This works, but it is not optimal, could crash
queue_listen_name = config["database"]["listen_channel"]
cur.execute("LISTEN %s;" % ext.quote_ident(queue_listen_name))
```

or better

```
from psycopg2 import sql

cur.execute(
    sql.SQL("LISTEN {};")
        .format(sql.Identifier(queue_listen_name)))
```

You can read more about formatting here: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html